# JAVA MySQL Connection ClassNotFound Exception

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

```
package cs352hw;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
      DB db = new DB();
            Connection conn=db.dbConnect(
              "jdbc:mysql://dijkstra.ug.bcc.bilkent.edu.tr",
              "",
              "");
      }

}


      //This Class is taken from http://www.java-tips.org/other-api-tips/jdbc/how-to-connect-mysql-server-using-jdbc.html
class DB
   {
    public DB() {}

    public Connection dbConnect(String db_connect_string,
      String db_userid, String db_password)
    {
            try
            {
                    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
                      db_connect_string, db_userid, db_password);

                    System.out.println("connected");
                    return conn;

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                    return null;
            }
    }
};
```

Hey guys my classes are given above

I am new at jdbc stuff

Please help me I am getting run time error such that

> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Thanks for any advice

Note: I don't know How to put the jar file into my classpath and bind it dynamically :S

Comment: You have to put the MySQL JDBC library (jar file) in the classpath of your program at runtime.

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/

Comment: i've put the jar file into every folder in my project but still gives the same error :(

Comment: You should remove your password from your post.

Comment: yes thanks :) I've removed now

Comment: Actually you will need to change the password on that server, if it's something that matters, as we can all see the password by looking at the revision history. :-/

Comment: I realised later the password was wrong :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download the [MySQL Connector/J](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/3.1.html) and add the .jar file in your application

Add the jar file in the `WEB-INF/lib`, if its a web-app, else in the `lib` folder of your project and then try to run

Comment: I've tried, I created a new folder, but I couldn't make it work :(

Comment: NetBeans 6.9.1 There are test, src, nbproject, build folders under my project folder

Comment: You need to right click on the project name in the project tab the go to Properties-> Libraries -> Press Add Jar/Folder... Browse and select your jar...and click OK...and build and re-run

Comment: thank you so much :) This was a too stupid question as programmer but I think everbody makes such mistakes :)